# I can only pass my $_GET variable to the header() method after sumitting the form (POST method)

Tags: php, forms, get

Good morning, afternoon or night :D

I want to pass my $_GET['area'] variable to a method, but after submitting the form, it only let me pass such variable to the header() method:

Note: This is the variable from the URL I want to pass: /index.php?**area=work**

**I have a index.view.php with a button:**

`<a href="crearArt.php?area=<?php echo $_GET['area'] ?>" >Add new article</a>`

From the URL, the button receives the $_GET['area'] and when I click the button it takes me to the area where I can create new  articles, **here is the code of crearArt.view.php file:**

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="POST">

    //... Bunch of inputs

    <button type="submit" name="crearArticle">Create New Content</button>

</form>
```

When I click on "Create New Content" (submitting the form), the crearArt.php file should get the $_GET['area'] variable and pass it to the $addDataToDB() method but that doesn't happens, if I put a print_r() inside the if condition to check if the variable it doesn't show the variable.

Furthermore, if I pass the variable to the header() method it does work, meaning that (I think) the variable still there.

**Here the crearArt.php file**

```
<?php

    $inputNames = [];
    $inputValues = [];

    if(isset($_POST['crearArticle'])){

        // Get all inputs from the form
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
            if($key !== 'crearArticle'){
                // This will NOT add the button' name property when the form gets submitted
                array_push($inputNames, $key);
                array_push($inputValues, $value);
            };
        };

        // Add values to WorkDB || CodeDB
        $addDataToDB($inputNames, $inputValues, $_GET['area']);

        // Return to index.php?area=??
        header('Location: index.php?area='.$_GET['area']);

    } // END MAIN IF
?>
```

Sumerizing, when I press on "Create New Content" it should pass the variable to $addDataToDB() but it doesn't do it, even though the URL has the $_GET['area'] var with it: /crearArt.php?**area=work**

**Question:**
Is there a way to get this variable without creating hidden inputs in the crearArt.view.php?

Thanks in advance

PS: I'm new into PHP.

**In addition**
I tried creating a var outside the if conditional and then passing it to the method but that doesn't work either.

By using that variable I'm gonna let the function "know" from which area I come from so the function "know" to which database it has to refer to.

If I use variable as a string ('work'), it does work.

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.

Comment: @Quentin, yes, but I will try to resolve first the issue I have with the $_GET and then I will sanitize the inputs. Thanks

Comment: As a general rule, many bad security practises create other problems as side effects. Fixing them up front often avoids the need to debug a more visible problem.

Answer (score -1):

Each HTTP request you make has its own URL.

The request you make to `crearArt.php?area=<?php echo $_GET['area'] ?>` and the request you make to `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>` are different requests with different query strings and will have different values in `$_GET`.

> `<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>"`

[According to the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), `PHP_SELF` is:

> The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.

You haven't put a query string in your URL.

When you submit the form `$_GET['area']` won't exist.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I think I found why it was correctly redirecting me and it wasn't the header() method. Thank you for your time :)